# Sides of the triangles are in G.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Question:-
The sides of a triangle are in G.P. and it's largest angle is twice the smallest one. Prove that the common ratio of the G.P. lies in the interval $(1,\sqrt{2})$

---

Attempt at a solution:-
[image: Sides of a triangle in G.P.]

First of all, I calculated the range of the values of the common ratio $r$ of the G.P. by solving the following three inequalities simultaneously:-

$$ar^2+ar\gt a \\$$ 
$$ar^2+a \gt ar \\$$ 
$$a+ar\gt ar^2 \\$$

The range of the common ratio comes out to be $$r \in \left[ \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$$

And as stated in the question $\angle A= \angle B$

So, by using the sine rule,
$$\dfrac{ar^2}{sin2B}=\dfrac{ar}{sin3B}=\dfrac{a}{sinB}$$

And, also taking the help of the cosine law, I arrived at $$\cos^2B(4r)-2\cos B-r=0$$
Then, as $D \ge 0$ for the solutions of $\cos B$ to be real. We get the codition $4+16r^2 \gt 0$, which is always true. So, I tried bounding the roots of the quadratic of $\cos B$.

---

Getting Stuck:-

I think that's where I am getting stuck, or if you could provide me with any other path for arriving at the, solution.

Comment: I see how you get the following: $$\frac{ar^2}{\sin 2B}=\frac{a}{\sin B}$$ However, you also have the fraction $\frac{ar}{\sin 3B}$. Where does the $3B$ come from?

Comment: From the fact that $A+B+C=180°$ and as $\angleA=2\angleB$, so $3B+C=180°$, Hence $C=180°-3B$, and $\sin C= \sin (180°-3B)= \sin(3B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, as you said, $ar^2$ is opposite a bigger angle than $a$, so:
$$ar^2 > a \implies r^2 > 1 \implies r > 1$$

Note that since the triangle has the angle $2B$, we know that $2B < 180^\circ$, or that $B < 90^\circ$, so $0 < \cos B < 1$.

By Law of Sines, we have:
$$\frac{ar^2}{\sin 2B}=\frac{a}{\sin B}$$
Divide both sides by $a$:
$$\frac{r^2}{\sin 2B}=\frac{1}{\sin B}$$
Take cross-product:
$$r^2\sin B=\sin 2B$$
Use the double-angle identity:
$$r^2\sin B=2\sin B\cos B$$
Divide both sides by $2\sin B$:
$$\frac{r^2}{2}=\cos B$$
We can combine this with $0 < \cos B < 1$. What do we get from this inequality?

I'll let you take it from here. Good luck!

Comment: Applying $\cos B = \dfrac {r^2}{2}$ to the said inequality, we get the lower bound = 0.

Comment: As you have mentioned that the triangle has a side of measure $2 \angle B$ so $2 \angle B \lt 180°$, so we can do the same for the sum of any two angle of a triangle. Then, consider $$\angle A + \angle B \lt 180° \\$$ $$\angle 3B \lt 180°$$, so $$0° \lt B \lt 60°$$, hence $$\dfrac{1}{2} \lt \cos B \lt 1$$ which leads to $$\dfrac{1}{2} \lt \dfrac{r^2}{2} \lt 1$$ or, $$1 \lt r \lt \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: @Noble Mushtak, I built up on your solution and reached, thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @Mick I wrote $r > 1$ at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, letting a = 1, we can simplify our calculation a lot.

Lastly, in simplifying $\sin 3B$, you need the formula $\sin 3x = 3\sin x – 4 \sin^3 x$. The proof goes like this:-

[image]

By sine law, we have $\dfrac {1}{\sin \theta} = \dfrac {r^2}{\sin 2\theta}$.

After simplifying, we get $r = \sqrt 2 \sqrt \cos \theta$

By sine law again, $\dfrac {r}{\sin 3\theta} = \dfrac {1}{\sin \theta}$

Using the formula mentioned, we get $r = 3 – 4\sin^2 \theta$

From which, we get $r_{max} = … = 3$ occurred when $\theta = 0$; and $ r_{min} = … = 0$ occurred when $\theta = 60^0$.

Therefore, $r_{max} = \sqrt 2 \sqrt {\cos (0)} = \sqrt 2$.

Similarly, $r_{min} = \sqrt 2 \sqrt {\cos (60^0)} = 1$.

Comment: Why have you used the results found from $r=3-4 \sin ^2 \theta$ and used  that result in the equation $r= \sqrt{2 \cos \theta}$, shouldn't there be only one set of values for $r$. Also the first set of values of $r$ that you found out as maximum and minimum doesn't agree with the set of values of $r$ for which the sides of a triangle are in geometric progression, i.e, $$r \notin \left[ \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$$

Comment: 1) The two different expressions for the **same r** can be equated but that will lead us to nowhere. 2) I think requiring the sum of the two smallest sides to be greater than the longest will be sufficient. That is, we just need $1 + r \gt r^2$. From which, we get $r \in [\dfrac {1-\sqrt5}{2}, \dfrac {1 + \sqrt 5}{2}]$. 3) Note also that $[1, \sqrt 2]$ is a subset of the adjusted range.

Comment: @user350331 you can ignore comment #2, but $[1, \sqrt 2]$ is still a subset of your computed range.

Comment: I am not saying that the interval $\left[1, \sqrt{2} \right]$, all I am saying is that, that the values of $r$ that you found out from the equation $r = 3 – 4\sin^2 \theta$ as maximum and minimum, i.e. $r_{max}=3$ and $r_{min}=0$ doesn't satisfy the range of values of $r$ for which it is in G.P.

Comment: @user350331 $r_max = 3$ is just a theoretical maximum. The actual value of r will be governed by $r = 3 – 4 \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Whats the difference b/w theoretical maximum and actual maximum.

Comment: It can never be reached because when $\theta = 0$, the whole triangle is degenerated.

Comment: Okay....then how do I know when to use theoretical Maxima and the actual minima concept

Comment: @user350331 The theoretical $r_{min} = 1$ should not be used. Say if r equals the lower bound 1, then the triangle will be ***equilateral***. This violates another given -- one angle is the double of the other.